# Unable to render content from WooCommerce database on a Gatsby page via the gatsby-source-woocommerce plugin

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, woocommerce, gatsby

I'm trying to source data from a WordPress backend, for display in a Gatsby front-end site using the default Gatsby hello-world starter.

I'm using the current version of WordPress (5.x), along with the gatsby-source-woocommerce plugin (from the original repo, not one of its clones). This has been set up in my gatsby-node.js file as this:

```
  /* Your site config here */
    plugins:[
      {       
        resolve: "gatsby-source-woocommerce",
        options: {
          api: 'localhost/wordpress',
          https: false,
          api_keys: {
            consumer_key: '<MY KEY>',
            consumer_secret: '<MY SECRET>',
          },
          fields: ["products", "products/categories", "products/attributes"]
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

I know this seems to be working, because I was at one point able to view content using http://localhost/__graphiql, and construct 2-3 sample queries which returned data OK. However, I was prompted to do a Gatsby update (I'm now on 2.4.82 in the site), and since then, I'm getting this error:

```
Missing onError handler for invocation 'building-schema', error was 'Syntax Error: Unexpected Name "WCProducts"

GraphQL request:1:1
1 | WCProducts/categories
  | ^'. Stacktrace was 'GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Unexpected Name "WCProducts"
    at syntaxError (C:\hcec\node_modules\graphql\error\syntaxError.js:15:10)
    at Parser.unexpected (C:\hcec\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:1463:41)
    at Parser.parseDefinition (C:\hcec\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:157:16)
    at Parser.many (C:\hcec\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:1518:26)
    at Parser.parseDocument (C:\hcec\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:111:25)
    at parse (C:\hcec\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:36:17)
    at TypeMapper.createType (C:\hcec\node_modules\graphql-compose\lib\TypeMapper.js:113:43)
    at Function.createTemp (C:\hcec\node_modules\graphql-compose\lib\ObjectTypeComposer.js:80:28)
    at Function.create (C:\hcec\node_modules\graphql-compose\lib\ObjectTypeComposer.js:56:21)
    at forEach (C:\hcec\node_modules\gatsby\src\schema\infer\index.js:44:41)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at addInferredTypes (C:\hcec\node_modules\gatsby\src\schema\infer\index.js:27:13)
    at updateSchemaComposer (C:\hcec\node_modules\gatsby\src\schema\schema.js:142:9)
    at buildSchema (C:\hcec\node_modules\gatsby\src\schema\schema.js:62:3)
    at build (C:\hcec\node_modules\gatsby\src\schema\index.js:105:18)
    at buildSchema (C:\hcec\node_modules\gatsby\src\services\build-schema.ts:19:3)'
```

I set up this file as my test index.js:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"

const IndexPage = props => {

  return (
    <>
      <p>THis is a test!</p>
      <ul>
        {data.products.edges.map(({ node }) => {
          <li>{node.name}</li>
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

export default IndexPage;

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    allWcProducts {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          name
          slug
          regular_price
          price
          short_description
          description
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

I've run gatsby develop numerous times, as well as gatsby clean to make sure it's not a caching issue; I've even stripped it back to just render plain text, but it's coming back with the same error throughout. I've also looked at the similar questions in SO, but none of them seem to apply; some are very specific, and others have more advanced requirements than me.

I'm struggling to figure out why I'm getting this error - I know the gatsby-source-woocommerce plugin is a couple of years old, but - assuming I can get it working, it's the only one I've found that gives me what I need so far. I am aware of a more recent version (gatsby-source-wordpress-experimental), but haven't found any docs that help explain how to query it for WooCommerce content, just WordPress. (I know that one is still being developed, so is in a state of flux - I need something more solid, even if it is a little older!)

Can anyone please point me in the right direction, and help figure out how I can get my query to render content in a Gatsby page?

Comment: What's your Node version? Try updating it to 12

Comment: I've checked it - node -v says it is 12.15.0